# How to avoid page-object deprecated for checkbox

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, pageobjects, page-object-gem

I use cucumber since one year, and I am adding page-object-gem into it since few weeks. 
When I execute the test, I get message :

> DEPRECATION WARNING
>   You are calling a method named checkbox at commentPage.rb:23:in `block in delete_comment'.
>   This method does not exist in page-object so it is being passed to the driver.
>   This feature will be removed in the near future.
>   Please change your code to call the correct page-object method.

(I have got the same for other cases, but this "trivial" example should be easier to explain)

I search a way to avoid that, but it seems complicated.

For the test, I am checking a page, on which there is a table. Each row show a line, and I need to check the checkbox of a particular line.

My code in the pageObject:

```
table(:comment_list, :class => 'comments')
button(:delete, :text => "Delete")

def delete_comment (text)
  self.comment_list_element.each do |row|
    if row.text.include? "#{text}"
      row.checkbox.set
      self.delete
      return true
    end
  end
  false
end
```

Did I need a pretreatment of my table to use it during the test ?

Comment: row.checkbox.set (the only line with "checkbox" inside ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting the warning because you are calling a method that is on Watir and not page-object (`checkbox` method on a table row).  If you want to access the Checkbox you can simply call the method that will return the nested element.  This would change that portion of the call to `row.checkbox_element`.  But you next call will also get the same issue.  First of all the `set` method does not exist on CheckBox.  In page-object the methods are `check` and `uncheck`.  The full call should be:

`row.checkbox_element.check`

The reason you are getting the deprecation error is because I plan to remove the forwarding of calls to the underlying driver in the future.  This ability really causes a lot of problems in complex situations.

Comment: Ah. I tried the `checkbox_element` but forgot that it was `check` instead of `set`. I think this should be the acceped answer.

Comment: how do you uncheck a checkbox without using the deprecated method?

Comment: It's a little old, but as Cheezy says in his post, you can just use the uncheck method.

`row.checkbox_element.uncheck`

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `row` is a `PageObject::Elements::TableRow`, which does not have a `checkbox` method defined. I have not come across any examples where page-object elements were chained.

As a workaround, you could convert the `PageObject::Elements::TableRow` to a regular `Watir::TableRow` by doing:

```
row.element
```

So your code will work if you do:

```
row.element.checkbox.set
```