# Getting deprecation warnings when calling methods on elements - Could use some advice

Tags: ruby, page-object-gem

I am getting deprecation warnings pretty frequently when calling methods on page object elements. This signals to me that I may not be using the gem as intended yet. I could use some help, could anyone recommend a better way to handle something like this?

I am working with a page containing a list of divs that each hold a checkbox element. In other words, something like this:

```
<div class="item-checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></div>
<div class="item-checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></div>
<div class="item-checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></div>
```

---

I would like to access a checkbox by index, and then check it when needed. Here is what I currently have:

```
    def select_checkbox(index)
       fail "Nothing in list" unless checkboxes.length > 0
       checkbox = self.checkboxes[index].checkbox_element
        if checkbox.exists?
           checkbox.set
        else
           fail "could not select a checkbox at index #{index} - check that it exists"
        end    
     end  

     protected
     def checkboxes
        div_elements(:class=> 'item-checkbox')
     end
```

This works, however I get a deprecation warning on line 5, checkbox.set. Changing it to checkbox.click clears it up. Nevertheless, I am not convinced that I am doing this the "page-object gem" way. Using watir-webdriver, divs gives me an array to work with, and I can accomplish the same thing in a similar way. Has anyone done anything like this using the gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have above looks fine except the `set` method does not exist on the `CheckBox` element.  Instead, there are `check`, `uncheck`, and `checked?` methods.  I think you can safely change your above method to this:

```
def select_checkbox(index)
   fail "Nothing in list" unless checkboxes
   checkbox = self.checkboxes[index].checkbox_element
    if checkbox.exists?
       checkbox.check
    else
       fail "could not select a checkbox at index #{index} - check that it exists"
    end    
 end  

 protected
 def checkboxes
    div_elements(:class=> 'item-checkbox')
 end
```

Another way to possibly do this is to declare the divs in the class like this:

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  divs(:checkbox, :class => 'item-checkbox')

  def select_checkbox(index)
     fail "Nothing in list" unless checkboxes
     checkbox_elements[index].checkbox_element.check
   end  
end
```

In this case you are still checking to see if there are any checkbox divs on the page.  In the second line of the method you will fail if the checkbox does not exist so it takes care of the condition you guarded against.

-Cheezy

Comment: Thanks Cheezy, the second way is something I was looking for since it's more consistent with the page object pattern. I had to change the first line of the method block to `fail "Nothing in list" unless checkbox_elements`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `checkbox.check`, not `checkbox.set`.

Here is a similar SO thread for reference:

[How to avoid page-object deprecated for checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479624/how-to-avoid-page-object-deprecated-for-checkbox)